# Issues sending an array with JSON (TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable)

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to send a request to a server with some JSON, but I keep getting a TypeError about it not being serialized. I tried json=data and using headers, but it keeps throwing that error.

Could this be the variables inside the request, or something else?

**Short Error:**

```
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

**Traceback:**

```
Ignoring exception in command limiteds:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\foo\Documents\Programs\Python\foo.py", line 471, in limiteds
    send_trade = requests.post(send_trade_api,data=json.dumps(req), headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
**discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable**
```

**Full Code:**

```
    req = {
    "offers": [
        {
            "userId": {our_userid},
            "userAssetIds": [
                {our_userAssetId}
            ],
            "robux": 0
        },
        {
            "userId": {userid},
            "userAssetIds": [
                {userAssetId}
            ],
            "robux": 0
        }
    ]}

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}

    send_trade_api = 'https://trades.roblox.com/v1/trades/send'

    send_trade = requests.post(send_trade_api,data=json.dumps(req), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use list instead of set when converting to json, but if your really need to use set should deal without third-party modules (I think there are still some sophistications to do this manually).

But the reciever will still get list.

Just check this instruction: https://appdividend.com/2022/06/23/python-set-to-json/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```py
"userAssetIds": [
    {our_userAssetId}
],
```

And this:

```py
"userAssetIds": [
    {userAssetId}
],
```

Are sets in lists. To avoid that you should just write the code this way:

```py
"userAssetIds": [
    our_userAssetId,
],
```

The sets are predefined by similar syntax like dicts, but there are no `:` separators, so set is defined for example by using syntaxes like:

```py
{1}
...
{1, 2, 3}
```

Also you need to change your `userId` key value too.

Comment: I think I have this all wrong in the first place. The API reference says that you have to have a parameter, so should that JSON be inside a set? API reference screenshot: https://ibb.co/gMjX1XJ

Comment: I don't know if you understand what are you trying todo... basically you want to put *variable* in list, not *set* in list, so this is why you do syntax using `[variable]`, not by `[{variable}]` way. So you change `"userId": {our_userid}` to `"userId": our_userid` and et cetera.